# Esri : 502 bad gateway when using a widget

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-server, bad-gateway, http-status-code-502

I am working on a web application based on arcopole builder by ESRI.
I have different widgets on my application, and one of them doesn't work correctly, it returns the 502 bad gateway error.
At first, I tried to delete all the parameters (cookies) of the browser I use, and it worked for a while.
Now, I have this error even after deleting the parameters or using another browser.

Any suggestion to solve this problem.

Thank you :)

Delete the browser parameters and using a different browser.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.